# IoC container - inject new DbContext instance only for specific services

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control

My C# web application uses Entity Framework 7 code-first. The `DbContext` is scoped to the lifetime of the HTTP request. There is a `UnitOfWork` class that wraps this `DbContext`. This gets injected into most of the services that need to perform Crud operations on the database.

The application also has an `AuditService` which is used to audit errors when exceptions are thrown. I don't want to inject the `DbContext` that is scoped to the HTTP request into this service because if an exception is thrown I only want to save the audit entry to the database and disregard any other pending changes. So it makes sense to inject a new instance of the `UnitOfWork`/`DbContext` in this case.

Is it possible to configure an IoC container so that when a `UnitOfWork` is injected into the `AuditService`, it should instantiate a new instance of the UnitOfWork (wrapping up a new instance of the `DbContext`)? But for all other services the `UnitOfWork`/`DbContext` that is scoped to the HTTP request should be injected instead?

I'm using Microsoft's built-in IoC container that comes with ASP.NET Core however examples using other IoC containers (e.g. StructureMap) would also be helpful.

Comment: Since your `AuditService` is such a specific adapter, I would probably let it create and dispose the `DbContext` itself internally; so not injecting the `DbContext` at all. This will make things really explicit and simplify your configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have wrote that examples are fine using other IOC containers, so I will use [Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject) as base of my answer.

The goal you would like to achieve is called [Contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding). Quoting from the Ninject wiki, that you can:

> ... register more than one binding for a type. There are two primary reasons one might want to register multiple type bindings
>
> 1. Multiple bindings – for contextual binding taking the context into consideration
> 2. Multiple bindings – for Multi-Injection

I think that you are looking out for the first type or registration, whereas you specify binding constraint using the `WhenInjectedInto()` helper. An example of such binding should look like:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(AuditService));
```

If it's not supplied, the default [object scope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) is `Transient`, which means:

> A new instance of the type will be created each time one is requested.

You can change this to your desired scope as you like, for example:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(AuditService)).InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: Doesn't Ninject support ASP.NET Core 1.0? Some of the newer IoC frameworks plug into ASP.NET's `IServiceCollection` and add extension Methods that add functionalities specific to this framework (decorators etc)? Should be noted as the question is specifically about ASP.NET Core

Comment: Ah! Great, thank you for pointing that out. Somehow I have completely missed that part of the specification in the question :\

Comment: @Tseng after digging around for information, it seems like there is no native support in Ninject for ASP.NET core, and vice versa.